# is there anyway to not optimise our app ?

Tags: android, react-native, optimization

in our app we need to poll location for frequently, and we don't want optimisation battery for our app, is there any way to set that one programatically ?

like I need to get isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations always true. so that our code will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to set that one programatically ?

No.

> like I need to get isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations always true. so that our code will work

No.

> in our app we need to poll location for frequently

Some users will want your app to work with locations frequently. Some users would prefer better battery life. Hence, it is the user's choice whether to add your app to the battery optimization whitelist.